# Getting Error No rule to make target while installing libvpx

Tags: c, libvpx

I am following a [tutorial](https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/webm-tools/+/master/vpx_ios/README.VPXExample) that allows me to build the VPX framework for iOS.

When running:

```bash
../libvpx/build/make/iosbuild.sh
```

I keep getting...

output:

```bash
make: *** No rule to make target `dist'.  Stop.
iosbuild.sh failed because: build exited with error (2)
```

Does anyone know what this error might mean?

I have tried:

- creating the directory **dist** .
- supplying an output directory when running the command.

...which has not worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

**iosbuild.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/sh
##
##  Copyright (c) 2014 The WebM project authors. All Rights Reserved.
##
##  Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
##  that can be found in the LICENSE file in the root of the source
##  tree. An additional intellectual property rights grant can be found
##  in the file PATENTS.  All contributing project authors may
##  be found in the AUTHORS file in the root of the source tree.
##
##
## This script generates 'VPX.framework'. An iOS app can encode and decode VPx
## video by including 'VPX.framework'.
##
## Run iosbuild.sh to create 'VPX.framework' in the current directory.
##
set -e
devnull='> /dev/null 2>&1'

BUILD_ROOT="_iosbuild"
CONFIGURE_ARGS="--disable-docs
                --disable-examples
                --disable-libyuv
                --disable-unit-tests"
DIST_DIR="_dist"
FRAMEWORK_DIR="VPX.framework"
FRAMEWORK_LIB="VPX.framework/VPX"
HEADER_DIR="${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Headers/vpx"
SCRIPT_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
LIBVPX_SOURCE_DIR=$(cd ${SCRIPT_DIR}/../..; pwd)
LIPO=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos${SDK} -find lipo)
ORIG_PWD="$(pwd)"
ARM_TARGETS="arm64-darwin-gcc
             armv7-darwin-gcc
             armv7s-darwin-gcc"
SIM_TARGETS="x86-iphonesimulator-gcc
             x86_64-iphonesimulator-gcc"
OSX_TARGETS="x86-darwin16-gcc
             x86_64-darwin16-gcc"
TARGETS="${ARM_TARGETS} ${SIM_TARGETS}"

# Configures for the target specified by $1, and invokes make with the dist
# target using $DIST_DIR as the distribution output directory.
build_target() {
  local target="$1"
  local old_pwd="$(pwd)"
  local target_specific_flags=""

  vlog "***Building target: ${target}***"

  case "${target}" in
    x86-*)
      target_specific_flags="--enable-pic"
      vlog "Enabled PIC for ${target}"
      ;;
  esac

  mkdir "${target}"
  cd "${target}"
  eval "${LIBVPX_SOURCE_DIR}/configure" --target="${target}" \
    ${CONFIGURE_ARGS} ${EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS} ${target_specific_flags} \
    ${devnull}
  export DIST_DIR
  eval make dist ${devnull}
  cd "${old_pwd}"

  vlog "***Done building target: ${target}***"
}

# Returns the preprocessor symbol for the target specified by $1.
target_to_preproc_symbol() {
  target="$1"
  case "${target}" in
    arm64-*)
      echo "__aarch64__"
      ;;
    armv7-*)
      echo "__ARM_ARCH_7A__"
      ;;
    armv7s-*)
      echo "__ARM_ARCH_7S__"
      ;;
    x86-*)
      echo "__i386__"
      ;;
    x86_64-*)
      echo "__x86_64__"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "#error ${target} unknown/unsupported"
      return 1
      ;;
  esac
}

# Create a vpx_config.h shim that, based on preprocessor settings for the
# current target CPU, includes the real vpx_config.h for the current target.
# $1 is the list of targets.
create_vpx_framework_config_shim() {
  local targets="$1"
  local config_file="${HEADER_DIR}/vpx_config.h"
  local preproc_symbol=""
  local target=""
  local include_guard="VPX_FRAMEWORK_HEADERS_VPX_VPX_CONFIG_H_"

  local file_header="/*
 *  Copyright (c) $(date +%Y) The WebM project authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
 *  that can be found in the LICENSE file in the root of the source
 *  tree. An additional intellectual property rights grant can be found
 *  in the file PATENTS.  All contributing project authors may
 *  be found in the AUTHORS file in the root of the source tree.
 */

/* GENERATED FILE: DO NOT EDIT! */

#ifndef ${include_guard}
#define ${include_guard}

#if defined"

  printf "%s" "${file_header}" > "${config_file}"
  for target in ${targets}; do
    preproc_symbol=$(target_to_preproc_symbol "${target}")
    printf " ${preproc_symbol}\n" >> "${config_file}"
    printf "#define VPX_FRAMEWORK_TARGET \"${target}\"\n" >> "${config_file}"
    printf "#include \"VPX/vpx/${target}/vpx_config.h\"\n" >> "${config_file}"
    printf "#elif defined" >> "${config_file}"
    mkdir "${HEADER_DIR}/${target}"
    cp -p "${BUILD_ROOT}/${target}/vpx_config.h" "${HEADER_DIR}/${target}"
  done

  # Consume the last line of output from the loop: We don't want it.
  sed -i.bak -e '$d' "${config_file}"
  rm "${config_file}.bak"

  printf "#endif\n\n" >> "${config_file}"
  printf "#endif  // ${include_guard}" >> "${config_file}"
}

# Verifies that $FRAMEWORK_LIB fat library contains requested builds.
verify_framework_targets() {
  local requested_cpus=""
  local cpu=""

  # Extract CPU from full target name.
  for target; do
    cpu="${target%%-*}"
    if [ "${cpu}" = "x86" ]; then
      # lipo -info outputs i386 for libvpx x86 targets.
      cpu="i386"
    fi
    requested_cpus="${requested_cpus}${cpu} "
  done

  # Get target CPUs present in framework library.
  local targets_built=$(${LIPO} -info ${FRAMEWORK_LIB})

  # $LIPO -info outputs a string like the following:
  #   Architectures in the fat file: $FRAMEWORK_LIB <architectures>
  # Capture only the architecture strings.
  targets_built=${targets_built##*: }

  # Sort CPU strings to make the next step a simple string compare.
  local actual=$(echo ${targets_built} | tr " " "\n" | sort | tr "\n" " ")
  local requested=$(echo ${requested_cpus} | tr " " "\n" | sort | tr "\n" " ")

  vlog "Requested ${FRAMEWORK_LIB} CPUs: ${requested}"
  vlog "Actual ${FRAMEWORK_LIB} CPUs: ${actual}"

  if [ "${requested}" != "${actual}" ]; then
    elog "Actual ${FRAMEWORK_LIB} targets do not match requested target list."
    elog "  Requested target CPUs: ${requested}"
    elog "  Actual target CPUs: ${actual}"
    return 1
  fi
}

# Configures and builds each target specified by $1, and then builds
# VPX.framework.
build_framework() {
  local lib_list=""
  local targets="$1"
  local target=""
  local target_dist_dir=""

  # Clean up from previous build(s).
  rm -rf "${BUILD_ROOT}" "${FRAMEWORK_DIR}"

  # Create output dirs.
  mkdir -p "${BUILD_ROOT}"
  mkdir -p "${HEADER_DIR}"

  cd "${BUILD_ROOT}"

  for target in ${targets}; do
    build_target "${target}"
    target_dist_dir="${BUILD_ROOT}/${target}/${DIST_DIR}"
    if [ "${ENABLE_SHARED}" = "yes" ]; then
      local suffix="dylib"
    else
      local suffix="a"
    fi
    lib_list="${lib_list} ${target_dist_dir}/lib/libvpx.${suffix}"
  done

  cd "${ORIG_PWD}"

  # The basic libvpx API includes are all the same; just grab the most recent
  # set.
  cp -p "${target_dist_dir}"/include/vpx/* "${HEADER_DIR}"

  # Build the fat library.
  ${LIPO} -create ${lib_list} -output ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/VPX

  # Create the vpx_config.h shim that allows usage of vpx_config.h from
  # within VPX.framework.
  create_vpx_framework_config_shim "${targets}"

  # Copy in vpx_version.h.
  cp -p "${BUILD_ROOT}/${target}/vpx_version.h" "${HEADER_DIR}"

  if [ "${ENABLE_SHARED}" = "yes" ]; then
    # Adjust the dylib's name so dynamic linking in apps works as expected.
    install_name_tool -id '@rpath/VPX.framework/VPX' ${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/VPX

    # Copy in Info.plist.
    cat "${SCRIPT_DIR}/ios-Info.plist" \
      | sed "s/\${FULLVERSION}/${FULLVERSION}/g" \
      | sed "s/\${VERSION}/${VERSION}/g" \
      | sed "s/\${IOS_VERSION_MIN}/${IOS_VERSION_MIN}/g" \
      > "${FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Info.plist"
  fi

  # Confirm VPX.framework/VPX contains the targets requested.
  verify_framework_targets ${targets}

  vlog "Created fat library ${FRAMEWORK_LIB} containing:"
  for lib in ${lib_list}; do
    vlog "  $(echo ${lib} | awk -F / '{print $2, $NF}')"
  done
}

# Trap function. Cleans up the subtree used to build all targets contained in
# $TARGETS.
cleanup() {
  local res=$?
  cd "${ORIG_PWD}"

  if [ $res -ne 0 ]; then
    elog "build exited with error ($res)"
  fi

  if [ "${PRESERVE_BUILD_OUTPUT}" != "yes" ]; then
    rm -rf "${BUILD_ROOT}"
  fi
}

print_list() {
  local indent="$1"
  shift
  local list="$@"
  for entry in ${list}; do
    echo "${indent}${entry}"
  done
}

iosbuild_usage() {
cat << EOF
  Usage: ${0##*/} [arguments]
    --help: Display this message and exit.
    --enable-shared: Build a dynamic framework for use on iOS 8 or later.
    --extra-configure-args <args>: Extra args to pass when configuring libvpx.
    --macosx: Uses darwin16 targets instead of iphonesimulator targets for x86
              and x86_64. Allows linking to framework when builds target MacOSX
              instead of iOS.
    --preserve-build-output: Do not delete the build directory.
    --show-build-output: Show output from each library build.
    --targets <targets>: Override default target list. Defaults:
$(print_list "        " ${TARGETS})
    --test-link: Confirms all targets can be linked. Functionally identical to
                 passing --enable-examples via --extra-configure-args.
    --verbose: Output information about the environment and each stage of the
               build.
EOF
}

elog() {
  echo "${0##*/} failed because: $@" 1>&2
}

vlog() {
  if [ "${VERBOSE}" = "yes" ]; then
    echo "$@"
  fi
}

trap cleanup EXIT

# Parse the command line.
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  case "$1" in
    --extra-configure-args)
      EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS="$2"
      shift
      ;;
    --help)
      iosbuild_usage
      exit
      ;;
    --enable-shared)
      ENABLE_SHARED=yes
      ;;
    --preserve-build-output)
      PRESERVE_BUILD_OUTPUT=yes
      ;;
    --show-build-output)
      devnull=
      ;;
    --test-link)
      EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS="${EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS} --enable-examples"
      ;;
    --targets)
      TARGETS="$2"
      shift
      ;;
    --macosx)
      TARGETS="${ARM_TARGETS} ${OSX_TARGETS}"
      ;;
    --verbose)
      VERBOSE=yes
      ;;
    *)
      iosbuild_usage
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  shift
done

if [ "${ENABLE_SHARED}" = "yes" ]; then
  CONFIGURE_ARGS="--enable-shared ${CONFIGURE_ARGS}"
fi

FULLVERSION=$("${SCRIPT_DIR}"/version.sh --bare "${LIBVPX_SOURCE_DIR}")
VERSION=$(echo "${FULLVERSION}" | sed -E 's/^v([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*$/\1/')

if [ "$ENABLE_SHARED" = "yes" ]; then
  IOS_VERSION_OPTIONS="--enable-shared"
  IOS_VERSION_MIN="8.0"
else
  IOS_VERSION_OPTIONS=""
  IOS_VERSION_MIN="7.0"
fi

if [ "${VERBOSE}" = "yes" ]; then
cat << EOF
  BUILD_ROOT=${BUILD_ROOT}
  DIST_DIR=${DIST_DIR}
  CONFIGURE_ARGS=${CONFIGURE_ARGS}
  EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=${EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS}
  FRAMEWORK_DIR=${FRAMEWORK_DIR}
  FRAMEWORK_LIB=${FRAMEWORK_LIB}
  HEADER_DIR=${HEADER_DIR}
  LIBVPX_SOURCE_DIR=${LIBVPX_SOURCE_DIR}
  LIPO=${LIPO}
  MAKEFLAGS=${MAKEFLAGS}
  ORIG_PWD=${ORIG_PWD}
  PRESERVE_BUILD_OUTPUT=${PRESERVE_BUILD_OUTPUT}
  TARGETS="$(print_list "" ${TARGETS})"
  ENABLE_SHARED=${ENABLE_SHARED}
  OSX_TARGETS="${OSX_TARGETS}"
  SIM_TARGETS="${SIM_TARGETS}"
  SCRIPT_DIR="${SCRIPT_DIR}"
  FULLVERSION="${FULLVERSION}"
  VERSION="${VERSION}"
  IOS_VERSION_MIN="${IOS_VERSION_MIN}"
EOF
fi

build_framework "${TARGETS}"
echo "Successfully built '${FRAMEWORK_DIR}' for:"
print_list "" ${TARGETS}
```

Comment: It's a problem with your makefile (and specifically that makefile not providing a `dist` target), not with the shell. Writing makefiles is a topic for a book, not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: That said, does your tutorial say anything about which current working directory to be in when running the command? The makefile to use is found relative to the directory you're in -- not the directory the script you're running is in unless that script goes out of its way to handle the case where they diverge -- so if the script was written assuming you'd be in the `build` directory or the `build/make` directory when running it, and you're instead somewhere else, that could explain an issue where the wrong makefile is being used.

Comment: Yes, it says to be in the `frameworks` directory. I am in said directory and still receive this failure. I have also provided a link to the tutorial. Its pretty brief.

Comment: We don't follow links here: a question needs to be self-contained enough that someone can answer it, learn from someone else's answer, or check an existing answer's correctness _given only the text of the question itself_ for that question to be on-topic. (To be clear, links are fine as supplemental information, but a question needs to still work without them).

Comment: That said, have you looked _in_ your makefile to see if there's a `dist` target? Looked at makefiles in other directories to see which, if any, provide that target? Part of building a good question is distilling a [mre]; if it requires pulling down an external codebase, it's not minimal, nor does it contain enough to reproduce the problem on its own.

Comment: The only string I see with *dist* in it is for var DIST_DIR on line#25 of *iosbuild.sh*

Comment: I have added the script for reference.

Comment: There is a `target_dist_dir=""` (line: 186 iosbuild.sh) but I do not think this is what the error is referring to.